# Asking prometheus http API in Java over time

Tags: java, prometheus, promql

I use Java to ask prometheus http API, and I met the problem about over time.

```
encodedUriString = "http://locahost:9090/api/v1/query?query=sum(node_cpu_seconds_total)";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
System.out.println("encodedUriString: " + encodedUriString);
ResponseEntity<HTML> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(encodedUriString, HTML.class);
HTML responseBody = forEntity.getBody();
System.out.println("Response: " + responseBody);
```

but I cannot get the answer. It's over time.

If I change the promql from `sum(node_cpu_seconds_total)` to `node_cpu_seconds_total`, then I can get the answer.
The problem happened in the code `sum`, but why?

If I change the code from Java to Python, I can get the answer when the promql is `sum(node_cpu_seconds_total)`.
Somebody can help?

Comment: did you try with an encoded URL like `http://locahost:9090/api/v1/query?query=sum%28node_cpu_seconds_total%29` ?